# Соединение с базой и выполнение запроса PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Добрый день сообщество!**

Решил углубиться в недра php и mysql с книжкой "PHP и MySQL. От новичка до профессионала". Книга мне очень нравиться почти уже всю проработал, при работе с книгой использую XAMPP, но не дает мне покоя один нюанс.

Я подключаюсь к определенной таблице БД использую скрипт:

```
try
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = ijdb', 'ijdbuser', 'pass');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $output = 'Невозможно подключиться к серверу баз данных! ' . $e -> getMessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

Который подразумевает подключение к конкретной базе данных сервера, а в итоге я не могу написать запрос типа:

```
SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM joke INNER JOIN author on authorid = author.id
```

сервер кушает запрос только в том случае если я его модифицирую:

> SELECT joke.id, joketext, name, email FROM **ijdb**.joke INNER JOIN **ijdb**.author on authorid = author.id

При первом варианте появляеться ошибка:

> QLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

*Каким образом избавиться от избыточности написания!?

Comment: Вам говорят, что не выбрана база, причем тут **избыточность написания**?

Comment: new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = **ijdb**', 'ijdbuser', 'pass')

Comment: Я же ее выбрал, зачем мне писать конструкцию вида **.** при выборе таблицы над которой выполняеться запрос?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[При подключении к PDO надо строго соблюдать формат DSN](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn). В частности, не добавлять отсебятину в виде пробелов, кавычек и прочих украшательств.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ijdb', 'ijdbuser', 'pass');
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Перерыл кучу тем в инете, ваш ответ помог. Никогда бы не мог подумать, что все дело в пробелах. Думал при обработке они убираются.